# How to set a property on a child component with React-Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Given the following simple components:

```
function ValueInput(props) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.value);

  function onChange (val) {
    setVal(val);
    props.onValueChanged(val);
  }

  return <input value={val} onChange={onChange}/>;
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.value);

  function onValueChanged (val) {
    setVal(val);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{val}</div>
      <ValueInput value={val} onValueChanged={onValueChanged}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm mounting them in order to test them with Enzyme and Jest:

```
const component = mount(<MyComponent value={42}/>);
const inputEl = component.find('input');
```

How do change the value of the inner component in order to that any change to `ValueInput` is reflected on `MyComponent`? I'm trying with the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
console.log(component.debug());
valueInputEl.setProps({value: 24});
// component.update();
console.log(component.debug());
```

And I get the following error:

```
ReactWrapper::setProps() can only be called on the root
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `shallow` mount your `MyComponent` and then test it by triggering the `onValueChanged` prop of your `ValueInput` child component and test the changes in your state by checking the value prop of the child component.

```js
  test('That the parent element is changed when the child component is changed', () => {
    const component = shallow(<MyComponent value={42} />);
    component.find(ValueInput).prop('onValueChanged')(24);
    expect(component.find(ValueInput).prop('value')).toBe(24);
    console.log(component.debug());
  });
```

And test for the behaviour of the `ValueInput`'s `onChange` methods in its own component tests so that it acts more like a unit test.

Comment: This is a good solution in that case. But Is there a way to setProp in the child component?